# How can I insert hindi text in mysql?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I am using an linode ubuntu vps. I have not set up any display and am just accessing terminal through putty.
I have created a database with encoding set to utf-8.
How do I insert hindi text into the database?
My research so far shows that i cannot enter hindi text on linux command line.
If i create the text on my local pc and try to paste it on my mysql command line, all it shows is ????.
I uploaded a file with hindi text created on windows and when viewed in vim it shows non readable text.
I installed ttf-indic-fonts, even then no luck.

This is what i see for समय on linux in vim: à¤¸à¤®à¤¯

I put it in my web directory and when i view it as in browser, it shows in hindi. but on linux terminal i only see unreadable characters.

Comment: did you make sure the file you save is saved with correct encoding?

Answer (score 0):

On vim, set file encoding to UTF8 and then change yur file.

```
:set fileencodings=utf-8
```

on vim and then save your file. It should display UTF8 characters

Comment: u mean on linux? i ran the above command and it still shows unreadable data.

Comment: I mean in vim. if you save the file with correct encodings, it should display text alright.

Comment: did this in vim too. still see same  à¤¸à¤®à¤¯ .

Comment: how about if you run `:set encoding=utf8`?

Comment: set to utf8; then saved and quit. when repopened still no readable text.

Comment: i did file -i filename and this is the output: 123456.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-16le

Comment: it might be because the file was saved with another format, and simply changing the encoding doesn't give you proper characters back. try saving the file from the first instance as utf-8

Comment: went back to windows, saved in utf-8. uploaded to server using ftp and then set fileencodings=utf-8. but still not readable

Comment: afraid, i don't understand. could you please explain a bit? got it output below.

Comment: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: i thought that you might have your machine locale to set incorrectly. but looks like even that is correct. can't be of any further help, sorry